# Windows 8 / Ubuntu 13.10 in dual boot - how to make Grub by default to manage it

Tags: boot, grub-efi

good afternoon every.
as it's said in the title, I have Windows 8 and Ubuntu on my laptop (EFI) and it boots automatically on Windows 8. To boot on Ubuntu, I have to change the boot order with the F9 key.
it's annoying so I want Grub manage it, what must I do?

Comment: Hi tomaRv and welcome to the site. The marked questions answer how to make both work under the same Boot manager.

Answer (score 1):

You *probably* have Windows installed in EFI mode and Ubuntu/GRUB installed in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. If so, either of the following should fix the problem:

- Prepare a USB flash drive or CD-R with my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) boot it, and test its ability to boot both Windows and Ubuntu. If it works, boot to Ubuntu and install the Debian-package version of the program. This procedure will cause the computer to boot via rEFInd, bypassing GRUB.
- Boot an Ubuntu live CD or USB flash drive *in EFI mode* and run the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool. This should fix the problem properly *if* you boot in EFI mode. If not, it may apply a hackish fix that might work, but could cause problems down the line.

If you try both of these solutions and neither works, post back with the URL that Boot Repair displays. If you prefer to determine if the assumption in my first sentence is correct before proceeding, run the [Boot Info Script,](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) post the `RESULTS.txt` file that it generates to a pastebin site, and post the URL to your document here.

Comment: I think it's fixed, I have used boot-repair and it boots on grub but there are many entries. thanks for you help ^_^